GAMS execution error showing that the model is infeasible due to a critical variable being at a bound
It shows that the solution is infeasible because an equation in the pre-triangular part of the model cannot be solved because the critical variable is at bound. I couldn't identify the critical variable.
I was expecting a feasible solution.
this is what I got
The user model has 229 constraints and 217 variables
with 850 Jacobian elements, 125 of which are nonlinear.
The Hessian of the Lagrangian has 30 elements on the diagonal,
25 elements below the diagonal, and 30 nonlinear variables.
Iter Phase   Ninf   Infeasibility   RGmax      NSB   Step  InItr MX OK
   0   0          1.1000000000E+01 (Input point)

** An equation in the pre-triangular part of the model cannot
be solved because the critical variable is at a bound.

Normally, the logs (the .lst file) give you the problematic variables, so often, you have to debug manually to understand your error
